# OneNote API "A syntax or other error was detected in a request your app sent"

Tags: onenote

I'm writing a library on php to communicate with OneNote API (based on https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISamplePHP).

I want to create Section and Pages.

The section created fine, but when I try to create pages always get the error:

```
A syntax or other error was detected in a request your app sent
error :{
       "code":"20011",
       "message":"The multi-part payload was malformed."
}
```

The body of page (mixed text + image):

```
--4ba4cdfe92db7bf32a8958dcad26d539951229d6570cfa0626c0adff64bf1ed9
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="Presentation"
Content-Type:text/html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Page 1</title>
  <meta name="created" content="2015-06-02T04:41:44-07:00" />
  </head>
  <body><img src="name:imageData1" alt="" width="488" height="181" /><p><p>Suspendisse enim turpis, dictum sed, iaculis a, condimentum nec, nisi. Praesent egestas neque eu enim. Suspendisse eu ligula. Vestibulum rutrum, mi nec elementum vehicula, eros quam gravida nisl, id fringilla neque ante vel mi. Morbi ac felis.</p>
</p></body>
</html>

--4ba4cdfe92db7bf32a8958dcad26d539951229d6570cfa0626c0adff64bf1ed9
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="imageData1"
Content-Type:application/octet-stream

SomeData

--4ba4cdfe92db7bf32a8958dcad26d539951229d6570cfa0626c0adff64bf1ed9--
```

The body of page (Text):

```
--5e4b8756b81ac1881459fe7691fb6a3e93e35540ccf71450095f6d5a679e27a5
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="Presentation"
Content-Type:text/html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <meta name="created" content="2015-06-02T04:45:33-07:00" />
  </head>
  <body><p><p>Nulla facilisi. Etiam vitae tortor. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Etiam rhoncus. Quisque ut nisi.</p>

<p>Suspendisse faucibus, nunc et pellentesque egestas, lacus ante convallis tellus, vitae iaculis lacus elit id tortor. Vestibulum facilisis, purus nec pulvinar iaculis, ligula mi congue nunc, vitae euismod ligula urna in dolor. Cras varius. Morbi mollis tellus ac sapien. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam.</p>
</p></body>
</html>

--5e4b8756b81ac1881459fe7691fb6a3e93e35540ccf71450095f6d5a679e27a5--
```

I used this url to create page
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/sections/$section_id/pages

I uploaded on a test server and works fine. But when i uploaded on live server(which server has ssl certificated installed) always get this error.

Any idea,
Thnx.

Comment: Havent used the onenote api but this - `[content_type] => application/json;`  - you are not posting json by the looks of things.

Comment: I used same thing that they used on OneNoteApiSample. 
This library work on test server, but not work on live server (ssl certificate installed). ?

Comment: If youre trying to upload images your content type should be something like `multipart/form-data` than json. You should include the code you use to submit the data to the one note api

Comment: I insert the code now, can you check please

Comment: Not working, if I change that, section not created. Now section created, but when i tried to create page, i get this error

Comment: Looking at what youve posted, thats a php class for interacting with the one note api. Where do you call the methods of this class?

Comment: I call this class from another class, when I prepare data (Section with pages) to send to OneNote

Comment: okay - is that code included?

Comment: Yes. This code is included

Comment: Okay sorry I cant seem to see it - can you direct me to where this code is. The code you are using to create a page.

Comment: Okay, the function createPPage is used to generate the body of page, and to create it

Comment: Yes okay but where do you call it and pass it parameters to create a page? Maybe Im misunderstanding how you are using this/how this is used. Anyway from looking at the code you have included its back to your **Header** If you are including images and the like the `content type` is not `json` and should be `multipart/form-data`

Comment: I used the same way, that they used on OneNoteApiSamplePhp

Comment: Are you calling `$this->initCurl();` ? this will set the correct content-type headers for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a very simple example of how this can be done.
The example shows how two images can be embedded in the new page's content + one additional link to download and embedded image.
All you have to do is paste your access token in the call to `$oneNoteMultiPartRequest->send()` and you're set.

For this example i've used an image which is embedded in the code but you can use any file / image you want (just remember to update the type attribute in the `<object>` and the `Content-Type` header for the appropriate request part.

Please note how the various attributes in the HTML (`<img src="name:...">` and `<object data="name:...">`) reference an existing request part by its name.

```
class OneNoteMultiPartRequest {
    protected $boundary;
    protected $parts = array();
    protected $responseInfo = null;
    protected $errorMessage = null;

    function __construct($presentationPartHtml) {
        $this->boundary = uniqid('', true);
        $this->appendPart("Presentation", "text/html", $presentationPartHtml);
    }

    public function appendPart($partName, $partContentType, $partContent) {
        $this->parts[] = "--{$this->boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$partName\"\r\nContent-Type: $partContentType\r\n\r\n$partContent\r\n\r\n";
    }

    public function send($url, $accessToken) {
        $cUrl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt(
            $cUrl,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array(
                "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary={$this->boundary}",
                "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken"
            )
        );

        $postData = implode($this->parts) . "--{$this->boundary}--";

        curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);        
        $response = curl_exec($cUrl);
        $this->responseInfo = curl_getinfo($cUrl);
        $this->errorMessage = curl_error($cUrl);
        curl_close($cUrl);

        return $response;
    }

    public function getResponseInfo() {
        return $this->responseInfo;
    }

    public function getErrorMessage() {
        return $this->errorMessage;
    }
}

$presentationPartHtml = <<<PRESENTATIONHTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Title of the captured OneNote page</title>
    <meta name="created" content="2013-06-11T12:45:00.000-8:00"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a simple multi-part HTML page.</p>
        <img src="name:image1"/><br/>
        <img src="name:image2"/><br/>
        <object data-attachment="Logo.png" data="name:image3" type="image/png"/>
    </body>
</html>
PRESENTATIONHTML;

$imageData = "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";

$oneNoteMultiPartRequest = new OneNoteMultiPartRequest($presentationPartHtml);
$oneNoteMultiPartRequest->appendPart("image1", "image/png", base64_decode($imageData));
$oneNoteMultiPartRequest->appendPart("image2", "image/png", base64_decode($imageData));
$oneNoteMultiPartRequest->appendPart("image3", "image/png", base64_decode($imageData));
$response = $oneNoteMultiPartRequest->send("https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/pages", "<YOUR ACCESS TOKEN>");

var_dump($response);
echo '<br/><br/>';

$info = $oneNoteMultiPartRequest->getResponseInfo();
var_dump($info);
echo '<br/><br/>';

$errorMessage = $oneNoteMultiPartRequest->getErrorMessage();
var_dump($errorMessage);
```

Comment: Thnx man, You solve my problem, this method is awesome **appendPart**,  I think my problem was with blank line.